# Facebook login pop up window won't show up on my React Native Expo app (using Firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-authentication

I am unaware of why my function won't send the user to the facebook login screen and ask for the users login credentials and permissions; any suggestions?

Here is my function:

```js
import firebase from './firebase.js';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';

export async function FacebookLogin() {

  const appId = Expo.Constants.manifest.extra.facebook.appId;
  const permissions = ['public_profile', 'email'];

  Facebook.initializeAsync({appId: appId, appName: "Foo"});
  
  const { type, token } = await
  Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
         appId,{
                permission: permissions
      } 
  );

  if (type == "success") {
    const credential =   
      firebase
        .auth
        .FacebookAuthProvider
        .credential(token);
  }
  firebase
   .auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or screenshots which might give more details on the issue ?

Comment: I do have more context given in this question I asked on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188103/why-wont-my-function-open-up-the-facebook-login-page-for-react-native-expo